# ASP.NET MVC - How to get an URL instead of an action link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, href, actionlink

I want to embed a URL in an applet parameter.

The only way I know to create automatically the URL is `Html.ActionLink()`, but I want only the inner `HREF` attribute, not the whole link.

Is there another way to get what I wan't, other that using `Regex` on the output of `ActionLink()` to get the `HREF` attribute?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get only the URL, you can use [`Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead of `Html.ActionLink()`.

It has a number of overloads, so you can give it the name of a route, or the name of the action and the controller, or a number of other options.

**Example:**

```
Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")
```

Comment: Additionally, Url.RouteUrl() will do the same thing, looking at the MSDN, it appears Url.RouteUrl() may be more universal, but it is unclear.  Url.Action - Generates a fully qualified URL to an action. Url.RouteUrl -  Generates a fully qualified URL (does not specify action).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: `Url.Action()` throws when the route cannot be mapped, `Html.ActionLink()` doesn't.